# IdentityServer4 encodes # in LoginUrl

Tags: angular-ui-router, identityserver4

I am building a frontend for IdentityServer4 using AngularJS with ui-router, but if I set `UserInteraction.LoginUrl` to `/index.html#!/login` the `#` gets urlencoded, breaking angular.

I have been trying to fix this, but I cannot find any relevant posts or documentation.

For Angular, the query string unfortunately has to come after # for $location to work, so removing #!/login from the url is not a valid solution.

Comment: Is having a function-specific entrypoint an option? E.g. `/auth/login` which loads the same angular app but has logic to kick off the sign in flow client-side? `identityserver4` will want to pass a returnUrl query string parameter to it too so you'll need to accommodate that too.

Comment: I want to make it as simple as possible and avoid having to use mvc views and whatnot. I am well aware of passing the returnUrl, that is what I am trying to get to work after all :) if I set LoginUrl to `index.html#!/login` the redirect becomes `index.html%23!/login?RedirectUrl=...` or something similar, which breaks routing in angular

Comment: If it was me I’d just have a host page (either static file or served via MVC) for the angular app that bootstraps it with the entry point you need.

Comment: I have considered it, but it feels like a bad solution. having the client needing to do an extra jump just to work around what seems to me like a bug in the frameworks just doesn't sit right with me. My hope is that there is some obscure method of telling identityserver4 to not urlencode that # - or that angularjs fixes the $location services search method to look before the #.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a bug given that this is a server-side framework that it must be able to append query parameters and these must be before the fragment. I'd imagine the cookie middleware will work similarly too.

Comment: Not being able to specify the url I want to use isn't a bug? :p

Comment: Frustrating it may be but the analogy would be trying to hitch a trailer to a car that already has a bike rack on the back. It's reasonable for the trailer manufacturer to assume you won't do this when writing the manual.

Comment: I must be expressing myself unclearly, because you clearly do not understand what I mean. I want the url to be `index.html#!/login?RedirectUrl=...` but it becomes `index.html%23!/login?RedirectUrl=...`

Comment: And I'm saying it's reasonable to for the framework (IdentityServer4 and ASP.Net Core cookie authentication middleware) to mandate that the URL you specify does not include a hash fragment or any other parameters. Combining a client side framework that relies on the hash with a server-side framework that assumes you won't do that is an edge case basically but one that's simple to work around.

Comment: And I'm saying it is reasonable to be able to control the behaviour of the framework to match whatever needs the consumer of said framework have.

Comment: You'll have to take that up with Microsoft and the IdentityServer4 guys ;)

Answer (score 0):

As a somewhat hacky workaround, adding a minimalist `login.html` with this script works;

```html
<script>
    window.location.href = window.location.href.replace('login.html', 'index.html#!/login');
</script>
```

But this is obviously not the ideal solution, as the client then has to make an extranous round trip to the server just to get redirected twice.

Answer (score 0):

in my solution i basically used the below for User interactions. The actual SPA application was loaded because i was using usefileserver which also internally serves the default file "/Account/index.html" - I created account folder inside of wwwroot

Once the index.html is loaded, the angular route takes care of the rest

```
 services.AddIdentityServer(setupAction =>
    {
        setupAction.UserInteraction.LoginUrl = "/Account#Login";
        setupAction.UserInteraction.LogoutUrl = "/Account#Logout";
        setupAction.UserInteraction.ErrorUrl = "/Account#Error";
    })
```

I did not get any encoding issues